# How to make scrollable (with touch) movie clip contains Buttons - AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scroll, touch, movieclip

Anyone knows about touch scrolling in AS3 ?

We can scroll with our hand vertical / horizontal, like a swipe gesture
but the object that we scroll is a movie clip that contains multiple button inside,
like this http://codecanyon.net/item/air-as3-touch-scroll/3914642
and
http://bassta.bg/experiments/ActiveSwipe.zip

but i onlu want to know how make movie clip (that contains multiple button ) can be scrolled?
Anyone knows the alternative way ? Please help Me :(
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Swipe Gesture event](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/)

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;  
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;  
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;  
import flash.events.GestureEvent;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE; 

var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();      
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x00c4ff); 
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,40,40); 
addChild(mySprite); 

function swipehandler(evt:TransformGestureEvent): void {
    myTextField.text = "I've been swiped"; 
    myTextField.y = 50; 
    addChild(myTextField); 
}
mySprite.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, swipehandler);
```

Comment: Additionally to the event itself, you will have to define the scrollRect property of the MovieClip. Please refer to this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect